# Is there a way to get data count from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I made a query that goes like this:

```
LLDPE = Inventory.objects.filter(rm_type='LLDPE')
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the **quantity** per `rm_type` that is named `LLDPE`. my models look something like this:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):

    RM_TYPES = (
        ('--', '----------------'),
        ('LDPE', 'Low-density polyethylene'),
        ('LLDPE', 'Linear low-density polyethylene'),
        ('HDPE', 'High-density polyethylene'),
        ('PP', 'Polypropylene'),
        ('PET', 'Polyethylene terephthalate')
    )

    item_type = models.CharField('item_type', choices=ITEM_TYPES, max_length=200, default='Not specified', null=True, blank=True)
    rm_type = models.CharField('rm_type', choices=RM_TYPES, max_length=200, default='Not specified', null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.count()` method to get the quantity on an specific queryset. Here is the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count)

> **count()**
>
> Returns an integer representing the number of objects in the database
>   matching the QuerySet.

In your example, try this:

```
LLDPE = Inventory.objects.filter(rm_type='LLDPE').count()
```

But, if you want to aggregate every `rm_type`, you should use [django aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: I need the get the quantity from the models. From what I know, **count()** counts the number of instances of the rm_type.

Comment: Checked the aggregation. Seems like the solution to my question is there. Thank you.